# Gradle verison updates for cucumber java junit selenuim framework

Tags: spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, gradle, junit, cucumber-java

I would like to update my framework versions to latest,
My current build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '22.0'
   compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-htmlunit-driver', version: '1.3.6'
   compile group: 'org.springbootframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
   compile('org.springframework:spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE')
   compile group: 'javax.jms', name: 'jms', version: '2.0'
   compile group: 'com.tibco.ems', name: 'tibjms', version: '6.1'
   compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
   testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '2.3.1'
   testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '2.3.1'
   testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '2.3.1'
   testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-path', version: '3.0.6'
   testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '3.0.6'
   testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.0.6'
   testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'xml-path', version: '3.0.6'
   testCompile group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit', version: '2.28'
   testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.8.0'
   testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.14.0'
   testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
   testCompile('org.juint.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0')
   testRuntime('org.juint.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0')
   testCompile 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan:courgette-jvm:2.3.2'
   testCompile io.github.prashant-ramcharan:webdriver-binary-downloader:1.2.2'
  
}
```

what are the other dependent versions to update. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: You may want to start with reading release notes https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/release-notes

Comment: It's helpful.. thank you @M.P. Korstanje